# How to disable (or remap) only specific win+... keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-key

While I found [a group policy setting to disable *all* shortcuts involving the Windows key](http://www.askvg.com/tip-how-to-disable-all-win-keyboard-shortcuts-hotkeys-in-windows/), I'd like to keep most of them and only disable those I consider useless and would like to use otherwise, e.g. <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> [opens the share charm](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/keyboard-shortcuts), which I *never* use but would rather map to the [toggle hidden files tool](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/keyboard-ninja/keyboard-ninja-toggle-hidden-files-with-a-shortcut-key-in-windows/). So,

> how to disable or remap keyboard shurtcuts involving the Windows key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved via [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/). To *disable* a hotkey, e.g. <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, use

```ahk
#h::return
```

but you can also remap it to another shortcut, e.g. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> via

```ahk
#h::#^h
```

For more complicated usage such as running specific commands, please refer to the [Documentation](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm).